# Published Angular Application IIS not opening from outside

Tags: iis-7.5

[image]I run into some serious problem.
I have a windows server 2008 R2 Enterprise. (Version : 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601)
and IIS version 7.5.
I have publish my angular application on this IIS and bind it to the https:xxxx.domain.com
and localhost:9090.
The website is running on "localhost:9090" or XXX.YYY.ZZ.13:9090 properly.
But the website is not running from outside when hitting the URL "https:xxxx.domain.com".

When hitting on the URL getting below

1. 503 - Service unavailable.
2. 403 Forbidden unauthorized access
3. After several refresh it opening my another website published on same machine.

I have created my subdomain on cloudflare.

I have tried all the Stack-Overflow solution but nothing is working in my case.

Comment: You will have to get started from substatus codes in IIS logs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-status-code There are too many 404 errors with different substatus codes, so without knowing yours nobody can help much.

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.